nginx conf on docker same for xampp
I'm following a youtube tutorial on how to setup docker with PHP. I came across this code for nginx configuration.
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    root /app/public;
    index index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
       fastcgi_pass   app:9000;
       fastcgi_index  index.php;
       fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
       fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
}

I'm wondering how can I setup this configuration to work the same way with xampp.
For example now. if I go to localhost/un-known-text it redirects back to index.php which is not the default behaviour of xampp.
Any help would be appreciated.

you can either do this by creating .htaccess file  in the root of your project  or setting virutal host  in apache cnofig (i dont recommend because youll have to change default apache config)
